# Need for demonstration about this usage of DataTypeAttribute (as documented in Microsoft's tutorial)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I'm moving from ASP.NET MVC to ASP.NET Core and while studying the documentation from Microsoft on this page https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/razor-pages/validation?view=aspnetcore-2.2

I've read this line about `DataTypeAttribute`:

> The DataType attribute can enable the ASP.NET Core framework to choose the right field template to render the data. The DisplayFormat if used by itself uses the string template.

This sounds unclear to me, all I know about `DataTypeAttribute` is something as mentioned in the above line (on the same page):

> The browser can enable HTML5 features (for example to show a calendar control, the locale-appropriate currency symbol, email links, etc.)

So that means the first quote really talks about something different from the second. I am seeking some clearer explanation to what it means (in the first quote) as well as (if possible) some interesting snippet of code to demonstrate that.

### Update

More precisely about what I want here, actually the difference between the 2 quotes as shown in the following snapshot:

[image]

I understand the first quote (in the snapshot) but really the second makes me confused, that's what I'm asking for a clearer explanation. The 2 points in one such a list cannot be the same, can they?

Comment: It means, for example, `DataType.Currency`, would help MVC to determine you need a numeric input for your property (so in your HTML you would get `<input type="number">`. Having said that, if your data type is numeric, then MVC already knows that it should generate a numeric input... I think use cases for `DataType` is very limited... perhaps `DataType.Email` is better example: if you annotate your property with `DataType.Email` and then display that property in your page, that property is automatically displayed as `<a href="mailto:EmailAddress.com">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The DataType attribute can enable the ASP.NET Core framework to choose the right field template to render the data. The DisplayFormat if used by itself uses the string template.

**the [`DataType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.datatype?view=netcore-2.2) is no more than an `enum` that describes the data types associated with data fields**, for example, `Date`,`DateTime`,`Currency`,`Url`,`CreditCard` and so on.

**`[DataTypeAttribute]` is only an indicator that instructs how to generate the tag**.

Consider the following model :

```
    [Display(Name = "Release Date"), DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }

    public DateTime ReleaseDate2 { get; set;
```

Both the `ReleaseDate` and `ReleaseDate2` has **the same declaring type of `DateTime`**. But the  rendered html type of the two fields are different:

```
<input class="form-control" type="date" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Release Date field is required." id="ReleaseDate" name="ReleaseDate" value="">

<input class="form-control" type="datetime-local" data-val="true" data-val-required="The ReleaseDate2 field is required." id="ReleaseDate2" name="ReleaseDate2" value="">
```

Note the first field is **`type="date"`** while the second one is **`type="datetime-local"`**. This is done automatically by `TagHelper` for you.

Also, if the fields have values, the `TagHelper` will know the `[DateTypeAttribute]` when constructing the `ModelExpression`, and **get a related format for this type** when processing this tag :

```
    string format;
    if (string.Equals("month", inputType, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {
        // "month" is a new HTML5 input type that only will be rendered in Rfc3339 mode
        format = "{0:yyyy-MM}";
    }
    else if (string.Equals("decimal", inputTypeHint, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) &&
        string.Equals("text", inputType, StringComparison.Ordinal) &&
        string.IsNullOrEmpty(modelExplorer.Metadata.EditFormatString))
    {
         // ...
    }
    else if ...
```

For more details, see [GetFormat(modelExplorer, inputTypeHint, inputType)](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/a266cecc0cbdf3883fa67f4e85b4c23055318b95/src/Mvc/Mvc.TagHelpers/src/InputTagHelper.cs#L436-L484)

When dealing with `datetime` & `date` & `time`, the [related formats](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/a266cecc0cbdf3883fa67f4e85b4c23055318b95/src/Mvc/Mvc.TagHelpers/src/InputTagHelper.cs#L58-L65) are generated by:

```
private static readonly Dictionary<string, string> _rfc3339Formats =
    new Dictionary<string, string>(StringComparer.Ordinal)
    {
        { "date", "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}" },
        { "datetime", @"{0:yyyy-MM-ddTHH\:mm\:ss.fffK}" },
        { "datetime-local", @"{0:yyyy-MM-ddTHH\:mm\:ss.fff}" },
        { "time", @"{0:HH\:mm\:ss.fff}" },
    };
```

As a result, the rendered view is :

[image]

This is how the `DateTypeAttribute` affects the display format.

---

Finally, you might wonder how the `data-` attributes are generated, you could take a look at the 
[source code of `DataTypeAttributeAdapter`](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/a266cecc0cbdf3883fa67f4e85b4c23055318b95/src/Mvc/Mvc.DataAnnotations/src/DataTypeAttributeAdapter.cs#L37-L38):

```
    MergeAttribute(context.Attributes, "data-val", "true");
    MergeAttribute(context.Attributes, RuleName, GetErrorMessage(context));
```

And also: [ValidationAttributeAdapterProvider](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/a266cecc0cbdf3883fa67f4e85b4c23055318b95/src/Mvc/Mvc.DataAnnotations/src/ValidationAttributeAdapterProvider.cs#L32-L78):

```
    ... 
     else if (type == typeof(CreditCardAttribute))
    {
        adapter = new DataTypeAttributeAdapter((DataTypeAttribute)attribute, "data-val-creditcard", stringLocalizer);
    }

    ... 
    else if (type == typeof(EmailAddressAttribute))
    {
        adapter = new DataTypeAttributeAdapter((DataTypeAttribute)attribute, "data-val-email", stringLocalizer);
    }
    else if (type == typeof(PhoneAttribute))
    {
        adapter = new DataTypeAttributeAdapter((DataTypeAttribute)attribute, "data-val-phone", stringLocalizer);
    }
    else if (type == typeof(UrlAttribute))
    {
        adapter = new DataTypeAttributeAdapter((DataTypeAttribute)attribute, "data-val-url", stringLocalizer);
    }
    ...
```

That means when dealing with `Email`, `Phone`, etc, ASP.NET Core will also reuses the `DataTypeAttribute` and generate different validation meta info for you (But `DateTypeAttribute` doesn't validate those fields).

---

**[Update]**:

Maybe using `DataType=Currency` as commented by [@Hooman Bahreini](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8211528/hooman-bahreini) is a better example.

But here the rendered`type` of `input` will not be `number` but a plain `text`. A `text` is not a HTML5 feature. Also, I'll use `DisplayFor()` as an example now.

Consider the following fields:

```
    [Column(TypeName = "decimal(10, 4)")]
    public decimal PlainPriceField { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
    [Column(TypeName = "decimal(10, 4)")]
    public decimal PriceWithDateType { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
    [Column(TypeName = "decimal(10, 4)")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "₿ {0:F3}BTC", ApplyFormatInEditMode = false)]
    public decimal PriceWithDateTypeAndDisplayFormat { get; set; }
```

By default, the database will store `decimal` with a scale of 2. To make this question clear, I add a `[Column]` annotation to declare them as `decimal(10,4)`.

And then, I set all the price fields `=1.2345`. Note all these fields has a value of `1.2345` in memory.

However, when rendered to end user, the result of `@Html.DisplayFor(item=>item.XyzPriceField)`will be :

- `PlainPriceField`:                       `1.23`
- `PriceWithDataType`:                     `$1.23` (instead of `1.2345` or `€1.2345` or anything else)
- `PriceWithDataTypeAndDisplayFormat`:     `₿ 1.235BTC`

The `PriceWithDataType` is rendered with a prefix `$`, which is a dollar sign determined by the current locale.

Be aware in this case there's no HTML5 support for currency at all(it will be rendered as a text). Also we didn't set a string template for this currency field.

**By checking the `[DataType(DataType.Currency)]` annotation, the `ASP.NET Core` framework knows this is a `currency` number and should be displayed in some particular format. Although there's no HTML5 support for currency, the end user will get a `$1.23`.** The way how ASP.NET Core choose the built-in format for certain `DataType` is already covered above.

Lastly, if you provide a `[DisplayFormat]` at the same time, ASP.NET Core will prefer that format defined in `DataFormatString`.

Comment: as in my question I already mentioned clearly what I know about `DataTypeAttribute` as in the second quote `The browser can enable HTML5 features ...` that I think your answer does exactly explain to that quote rather than the first quote `The DataType attribute can enable the ASP.NET Core fr...`. So that's what confusing me, the 2 quotes are separated into 2 different points (in a list of benefits of using `DataTypeAttribute`) as documented. Unless those 2 points are just one same thing, but if so why separating them?

Comment: @Hopeless  I mentioned that "if the fields have values, the TagHelper will know the [DateTypeAttribute] when constructing the ModelExpression, and get a related format for this type when processing this tag ". The format for `date` is `{0:yyyy-MM-dd}` and the format for `datetime-local` is `{0:yyyy-MM-ddTHH\:mm\:ss.fff}`

Comment: @Hopeles if I understand correctly, the explanation on how it chooses the template should make sense ?

Comment: that's still too vague, the difference between the 2 outputs (generated htmls) in your answer include both the format and the generated input element. The formats are different mainly due to the `DisplayAttribute` whereas the generated inputs are different mainly due to using `DataTypeAttribute` BUT this really involves the second quote (about HTM5 feature). Also I really thought that the first quote seemed to mean about some kind of `template selector` (by data type)

Comment: I really appreciate your answer with all you have typed, however I just wonder more about the difference here (between the 2 quotes), that's the point, you might focus too much on the detailed usage of `DataTypeAttribute` as well as how it could be used internally.

Comment: @Hopeless Did you give a try? **The `DisplayAttribute` here only affects the label name**

Comment: sorry, I had a mistake, really the format is not specified in your example (what in my head was the `DisplayFormatAttribute` - not `DisplayAttribute`). However as I confirmed before, really what you showed seems to explain for the quote 2 (involving `HTML5`, if the datetime input is not a feature of HTML5, a simple text of datetime will be rendered). By the way, please see my update in my question to make it clear on what I really wonder about. If you can point out the difference here I will be very happy to accept this answer, otherwise I would just up-vote it for your effort. Thank you!

Comment: @Hopeless I edit my answer to cover the format without HTML5 feature (rendered as plain text). If you have any further question, please feel free to update me.

Comment: your new example is tricky, just like a rare case pointing out the difference. Although I still doubt about the term (used in the first quote in the snapshot) `locale-appropriate currency symbol`, not sure if there is any such HTML5 feature, it seems to mean about the usage of `DataType.Currency`. Also what mentioned in the second quote seems to mean `input controls` other than static text (when compared with using `DisplayFormat` alone). And when it comes to `input controls`, almost are related to HTML5 features (corresponding to `DataType`).

Comment: I almost doubt that there is a misleading content with the documentation.

Comment: @Hopeless Although I don't think it's a misleading content, I'd like recommend people to post a content feedback right below that docs page if they find a bug or if they think it is not clear. By the way, the ASP.NET Core team is really nice to work with :) .